# When to use method vs setting a property in the constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to OOP, and I'm not sure when I should be *setting properties in the constructor* for my own convenience, as opposed to just *using a method*.

**Option 1 (method):**

```
class String {

    function __construct($word) {
        $this->word = $word;
    }

    function reverse() {
        return str_reverse($this->word);
    }

}
```

Then I can get the reverse like this:

```
$word = new String('potato');
echo $word->reverse();
```

**Option 2 (property):**

```
class String {

    public $reverse;

    function __construct($word) {
        $this->word = $word;
        $this->reverse = $this->reverse();
    }

    function reverse() {
        return str_reverse($this->word);
    }

}
```

Then I can get the reverse like this:

```
$word = new String('potato');
echo $word->reverse;
```

The second option looks nicer.

However, I was wondering if there are any pitfalls of using **Option 2** all the time?

Comment: this is not a oop problem. it's just common sense. i think the first one makes more sense, i dont see the need to store the reverse string in another property

Comment: Pitfall to option #2.... `$word->reverse = 'potato';`.... it's a public property, so you can set values without their being reversed.... protecting your properties makes the object "immutable", which means it's values can't be changed (or at least you can control any changes)

Comment: The constructor should be used to set properties *without which the instance is not valid*. Since the reversed string is derived from an existing property, then to me it makes sense to calculate it whenever it's required, in a public `reverse()` method. If it's ever possible to change the "word" property, then option 2 won't work, as it will return the initial reverse value.

Comment: Why not use static methods for such classes, constructor is not even needed

Comment: I tend to prefer option 1 since it allows me to add code in the ``reverse()`` function (e.g. for logging) that option 2 doesn't.

Comment: Suggestion: For instance properties, start with `private` visibility and raise it only when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr

You need to find out for yourself what works best for your context.

#### Value Object

Here's an example of a value object that might make sense to you:

- it holds state
- it is immutable
- invoking `$word->reverse()` returns a new instance of a value object, however, with the reversed string value

```
final class Word
{
    private $word;

    public function __construct(string $word)
    {
        $this->word = $word;
    }

    public function reverse(): self
    {
        return new self(strrev($this->word));
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->word;
    }
}

$word = new Word('potato');

echo $word->reverse();
```

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/ONklH

#### Service

Here's an example of a service:

- it doesn't hold any state
- invoking `$service->reverse()` requires passing in the word, it returns the word reversed

```
final class Service
{
    public function reverse(string $word): string
    {
        return strrev($word);
    }
}

$service = new Service();

echo $service->reverse('potato');
```

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/cKECo

#### Suggested Reading

- http://wiki.c2.com/?ValueObject
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object
- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html